# REST jBPM API, where is kie-services-client for v6.2

Tags: maven, jboss, jbpm

jBPM 6.2 is running nicely on JBoss. From a WebSphere v855 application (camel route) we want to use the jBPM REST API to communicate to jBPM. Preferably with as little as possible dependencies.

In the user guide chapter 17.2 REST the documentation says:

"When using Java code to interface with the REST API, the classes used in POST operations or otherwise returned by various operations can be found in the **(org.kie.remote:)kie-services-client** JAR."

See: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#d0e14165

Since the REST payload can be quite complex, it seems this is exactly what we want, use the api classes to generate the operations data (camel body for the REST call).

For jBPM 6.1 there is a [maven download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie.remote/kie-services-client) for the kie-services-client, for 6.2 not. Where is the 6.2 version?

Should we use another approach, can we use the 6.1 version or ...

Comment: Did yo find the client?

Comment: I didn't look for it since we don't need it. We only use the model and message classes which we set as apache camel bodies. Camel does the communication with jBPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the artifact may have changed.  See:[See Maven Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie.remote/kie-remote-client)

From [POM](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/6.2.0.Final/kie-remote/kie-remote-client/pom.xml):

```
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-remote</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
      </parent>
      <artifactId>kie-remote-client</artifactId>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Right now we're using 'kie-remote-jaxb-gen' and 'kie-remote-client'. That seems to be enough. They bring in a lot of other dependencies but for now its working. Maybe we have to exclude stuff later.